# Javascript/jQuery remove quotes from specifics JSON values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Right now I have ajax call that returns me this:

```
    "nodes":
        [
            {"ID":"87","score":"-0.2","dscore":"-0.4","x":"250","y":"250","name":"TEST","ticker":"TEST","datafrom":"0000-00-00","r":"28","fixed":"true","color":"grey"}
]
```

When I need this

```
  "nodes":
        [
            {"ID":"87","score":"-0.2","dscore":"-0.4","x":250,"y":250,"name":"TEST","ticker":"TEST","datafrom":"0000-00-00","r":"28","fixed":"true","color":"grey"}
]
```

So the real difference is between `"x"` and `"y"` values, first example they have double quotes, second they don't. I'm using this for `d3.js` so it needs to be without quotes, and I'm pulling a lot of that, that was just one line. So I can parse this via php/ajax/javascript, whatever is the most efficient. How would I go on about parsing the entire thing though?

edit: I said php since I use php to grab this info from the database, after which I do `json_encode($str)`, so it's parase-able there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that when source data is json-encoded, all fields in `nodes` array have "string" type, and so json encoder encodes them as strings, with quotes.

The most correct way to fix this would be assigning correct types to source data, so then json encoder would encode it as numbers, with quotes.

If you have any control on the side that *generates* json you get in reply, then just `intval`/`floatval` the numbers before you json-encode them.

If you don't have it, then convert it on js side, before passing to d3. Use `parseInt(nodes[i].x, 10)` or `parseFloat(nodes[i].y, 10)`, depending on what type of values `x` and `y` should contain. When converting strings to numbers in JS it is always important to specify second param "radix", or your numbers might be interpreted with some JS engines as octal if they begin with 0. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix) for more information.

For the reference:

```
$ php -r '$a = ["test" => "1.25"]; echo json_encode($a) . PHP_EOL;'
{"test":"1.25"}
        ^
$ php -r '$a = ["test" => 1.25]; echo json_encode($a) . PHP_EOL;'
{"test":1.25}
        ^
```

Comment: I have complete control over the side that generates data, however, I don't parse it at all. I do it like this:

`$grabme = $db->query("SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE somecol = '$somecol' ORDER BY ID DESC");
$res = $grabme->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$data['nodes'] = $res;`
Which I basically echo as json later on. Would I want to iterate throught `$data['nodes']` array and remove the quotes around `x` and `y` values? What would be the most efficient way to do this without disturbing the rest of the data order?

Comment: Ah, yes, I've experienced this exact problem in one of our little python scripts, and we fixed it by using that python lib's ability to specify types of different fields, so when fetching results they already would be typecasted to needed type (which also saved us lots of time spent on manual conversion).

I don't know whether it is possible or not with PHP's PDO (doubt it). But if you definitely know, which fields should be integer/float in reply (x, y in our example), then just convert them manually right after you fetch them:

Comment: ```foreach($data['nodes'] as $k => $v) { $v['x'] = intval($v['x']); $v['y'] = intval($v['y']); $data['nodes'][$k] = $v; }```

Comment: It's an insane problem to have right? Took me quite a bit to identify as well, since I've supplied the correct data to `d3.js` and it simply refused to work without any errors. Anyways, thank you! Beer is definitely on me!

Comment: And again, you don't "remove quotes", you typecast (convert type) from string to integer/float, and json_encode, instead, "does not add" quotes, since it only needs to do that for strings :)

Comment: Hehe, data is hard, glad I've helped! :)

Comment: Being asked to do stuff that isn't your job too! Cheers man, lifesaver!

Answer (score 1):

You can use parseInt to convert the string value to an integer.

```
var x = parseInt(jsonObj.get("x"), 10);
```

The 10 is to use base 10 when parsing.

Comment: Thank you! But I've picked the php method since it's simple and happens on the server, rather than on the client side. Somehow feels safer. But this worked well too!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, glad you got it figured out with PHP